# Changing opacity of the back-ground but not the text itself.

Tags: css

I am trying to create a loading screen but with no success.

Animation looks exactly as it is supposed to look but back-ground itself is a problem, whenever i am trying to change opacity, opacity of text changes as well.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow');
.yes
{
   background:black ;

}
.loading {
  font-family: PT Sans Narrow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
 color:black;
   top: 45%;
   left: 45%;
   
  position: absolute;
  color:white !important;
}

.loading:after {
  

 overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-animation: ellipsis steps(5,end) 1000ms infinite;      
  animation: ellipsis steps(5,end) 1000ms infinite;
  content: "...."; /* ascii code for the ellipsis character */
  width: 0px;


}

@keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 0.9em;    
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 1em;    
  }
}
```

```html
<body class="yes">



<p class=" loading ">Loading</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [RGBA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgb()_and_rgba()) as the background color. The 4th parameter of `rgba` (the a) is the alpha channel - the opacity of the color. The alpha is a number between 0 (fully transparent) and 1 (opaque).

```
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Since it's only the background color, it doesn't effect any of the children of the element.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow');

body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/600);
  background-size: cover;
}

.yes {
  height: 100vh;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.loading {
  font-family: PT Sans Narrow;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  top: 45%;
  left: 45%;
  position: absolute;
  color: white !important;
}

.loading:after {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-animation: ellipsis steps(5, end) 1000ms infinite;
  animation: ellipsis steps(5, end) 1000ms infinite;
  content: "....";
  /* ascii code for the ellipsis character */
  width: 0px;
}

@keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 0.9em;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 1em;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="yes">
  <p class=" loading ">Loading</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it going to fade away other elements of the page?

Comment: Nope. It's just the background color.

Comment: Right.. How can i make a view on top of the page to make other elements fade away?

Comment: Not completely invisible.

Comment: Use rgba with 0 < alpha < 1, for example rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) - half transparent black.

Comment: I've updated the example a bit. Now you a have semitransparent black background on an image. You can see that only the background of the `.yes` div is transparent, and the text is not effected.

Comment: Will it be fine to later on change classes of elements with: document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.add('yes');
When page is loading
document.getElementById("MyElement").classList.remove('yes'); when page is no longer loading? or is it a bad practice?

Comment: That's fine. This is a standard way of changing styling on elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to change the opacity for the background color, just try with RGBA. where the last argument is the opacity

```
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in your css class instead of **background:black**;

```
.yes{background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6); }
```

Always use rbga. This allows us to fill areas with transparent color; the first thee numbers representing the color in RGB values and the fourth representing a transparency value between 0 and 1 (zero being fully transparent and one being fully opaque). We have long had the opacity property, which is similar, but opacity forces all decendant elements to also become transparent and there is no way to fight it